# Creating an Image Button that Creates a Sound HTML

Tags: html, image, button, audio

Hi I am currently trying to make an image button ( of a speaker ) play an audio file for me.

```
<p><br></p>
<table>
<tbody><tr>
<th> Quick Clicks </th> 
<td style="text-align: center;">
<a href="#3" onclick=""><img src="https://zingtree-uploads.s3.amazonaws.com/images/59777e50293d71.47898028-416750-speaker.png" style="width: 145px; height: 145px;"></a>
</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">
<a href="#3" onclick="do_button_click(14, 7, 'Quick Clicks',0);"><img src="https://zingtree-uploads.s3.amazonaws.com/images/59777e50293d71.47898028-486417-Quick+Clicks.png" style="width: 145px; height: 145px;" ></a>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
```

Those are the two pictures i'd like to use and i'd like to make the first button play this audio file:

```
<a class="btn btn-lg btn-zingtree btn-block btn-primary" onclick="this.firstChild.play()"><audio src="https://thorswrench-my.sharepoint.com/personal/christiaan_karsavior_com/Documents/database%20media/sounds/dead%20battery%20clicking.mp3"></audio>Play</a>`enter code here`
```

Sorry, I know there must be a solution to this somewhere but I have failed to find one.

Answer (score 0):

At its most basic if you'd like to trigger `play()` on an `<audio>` you'll just need to find the element and setup a function that calls play(). You can set this up in a `<script>` tag at the bottom of `<body>` and call it from an `onclick` if you'd like.

```
let au = document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[0]
function playAu() {
  au.play()
}
```

The `<audio>` element just needs to be on the page somewhere. If there are multiple audio's you'll want to give them ids and selected them individually. If there is a problem with the file (source) that you are trying to play you will see that in the console.